# How do I convert a Windows UNC path to a mapped drive letter path with Python?

Tags: python, pathlib

I've seen the reverse of this question asked a lot but can't find info on this one.

A set of subprocesses I'm running in a script want Windows drive-letter paths (`M:\Some\Path\file.txt` instead of `\\my.subnet\someplace\Some\Path\file.txt`), but the UNC path is presented as an earlier input (which I don't have control over).

I am familiar with the `pathlib.Path.drive` function, which gives me `\\my.subnet\subnet`, but how would I get from that to the drive letter?

Comment: There is no guarantee that a given UNC path is mapped to _any_ drive, or to only _one_ drive. Where is this code supposed to run? Locally, on the machine that may or may not have the path mapped?

Comment: It’s on an enterprise with drives mapped administratively…. But that gives me an idea, I could just use a dict with the UNC roots and drive mappings.